# Why jQuery function is automatically calling show() method?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am learning jQuery. I made a button to show/hide a box using jQuery. It works well for the first time only. After first time it automatically showing the box after I hide it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" />
        <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-7LkWEzqTdpEfELxcZZlS6wAx5Ff13zZ83lYO2/ujj7g="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="playbox">
            <div class="button"><button>Hide/Show</button></div>
            <div class="box"></div>
        </div>
        <script src="./jQuery.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(".playbox").css({
                width: "100%",
                height: "50vh",
            });
            $(".button").css({
                width: "50%",
                height: "100%",
                float: "left",
            });
            $("button").css({
                width: "150px",
                height: "100px",
            });
            $(".box").css({
                width: "50%",
                height: "100%",
                background: "red",
                float: "left",
            });
            $('button').click(function () {
                $('.box').hide(2000, function () {
                    $('button').click(function () {
                        $('.box').show(2000);
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

jQuery version 1.11.3.

How can I fix it? Please help.

Comment: **Danger**: jQuery 1.11.3 has known security vulnerabilities. Upgrade to a supported version of jQuery.

Comment: I don't get it why you are styling your elements with jQuery instead of just CSS? Also you nested the listeners, why?

Comment: I recommend to update your jQuery version and startusing `toggle()` in this case.

Comment: Which version of jQuery should I use? @Quentin sir

Comment: @Engin sir, I am styling elements with jQuery because I am learning jQuery.

Comment: @DabanandaMitra — The current version.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you could fix that:

```
        $('button').click(function () {
            if($('.box').is(":visible")){
              $('.box').hide(2000);
            }else{
              $('.box').show(2000);
            }
        });
```

or use toggle():

```
        $('button').click(function () {
              $('.box').toggle(2000);
        });
```

Comment: The `toggle` method would me more practical.

Answer (score 0):

**Every** time you click the button you:

- Hide the box
- Add an event handler to show the box

So the second time you click the button you:

- Trigger the first event handler which:

  - Hide the box
  - Add an event handler to show the box
- Trigger the second event handler which:

  - Shows the box

Bind **one** event handler which behaves differently depending on if it is hidden or not.

You could write that logic yourself, but the [`toggle()` method](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) is already written.

Replace:

> ```
> $('button').click(function () {
>     $('.box').hide(2000, function () {
>         $('button').click(function () {
>             $('.box').show(2000);
>         });
>     });
> });
> ```

With:

```
$('button').on('click', () => $('.box').toggle(2000));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an inbuilt function in jQuery called `toggle`. Use it to hide/show on 1 click.

See below for example.

Thanks me later.

```js
$(".playbox").css({
                width: "100%",
                height: "50vh",
            });
            $(".button").css({
                width: "50%",
                height: "100%",
                float: "left",
            });
            $("button").css({
                width: "150px",
                height: "100px",
            });
            $(".box").css({
                width: "50%",
                height: "100%",
                background: "red",
                float: "left",
            });
            $('button').click(function () {
                $('.box').toggle(2000);
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="playbox">
            <div class="button"><button>Hide/Show</button></div>
            <div class="box"></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
            $('button').click(function () {
                $('.box').toggle(2000)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" />
        <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-7LkWEzqTdpEfELxcZZlS6wAx5Ff13zZ83lYO2/ujj7g="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="playbox">
            <div class="button"><button>Hide/Show</button></div>
            <div class="box"></div>
        </div>
        <script src="./jQuery.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(".playbox").css({
                width: "100%",
                height: "50vh",
            });
            $(".button").css({
                width: "50%",
                height: "100%",
                float: "left",
            });
            $("button").css({
                width: "150px",
                height: "100px",
            });
            $(".box").css({
                width: "50%",
                height: "100%",
                background: "red",
                float: "left",
            });


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```